# Ubuntu 12.10 Web app integration not working when Firefox is closed?

Tags: webapps

I just started using web app integration for facebook and gmail. The apps work only when gmail/facebook is open in Firefox. What's the point if it only works when the website is already open?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's intended to work.

If you don't like Facebook and Gmail taking up space in Firefox's tab bar, I recommend right-clicking on the tab and choosing "Pin as App Tab". This will make the tab turn into a small icon, which can't be closed while Firefox is open. It's very useful for tabs you want to have open all the time.